# NFS mount on Windows 8 non-enterprise

Tags: nfs, windows-8, windows-8.1

I've read the answers to a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/525473/how-do-i-mount-an-nfs-share-in-windows-8), but I'd like to ask it here with a very narrow scope. Assuming Windows 8, not enterprise (which means no services for unix applications providing native NFS capabilities), how can I mount an NFS share?

edit: Third party software is acceptable, and the only answer, I think.

Comment: look other answer in the post you linked :)   there is nfs client you can install, a free's one; http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/windows/

Comment: That is a little do-it-yourself... I am hoping for an answer that involves installing some software, but am not up to compiling something myself. Many people who went from windows 7 to 8 have lost the ability to use their NFS NAS, and a good answer to this question would be very helpful to a lot of people.

Comment: Check the page, there is a binary available to download :)  http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/windows/120612/ms-nfs41-client-x64.zip

Comment: I didn't see that, I'll try it :)

Comment: FWIW, I am running enterprise 8.1 with the NFS utils to mount a remote NFS share, and got a BSOD within 4 hours of setting it up. Might be more reliable using the third party software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, officially you **can't**. Here's why (may be you know it already) for reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2769923

> Services for Network File System (NFS) feature is available only in
>   the Windows 8 Enterprise edition. This feature is not available in
>   Windows 8 and Windows 8 Pro editions. Users when upgrading from
>   Windows 7 Ultimate or Windows 7 Enterprise edition to Windows 8 Pro
>   edition can no longer use Services for NFS feature.

So what are the alternatives?
Microsoft says clear and concise:

> In order to continue to use Services for NFS feature in Windows 8
>   client, Windows 7 users will have to upgrade to Windows 8 Enterprise
>   edition.

So, the remaining options I can think of,

- Doing some kind of hack.
- Installing some third party software.

The other option that comes to my mind, is to use `samba` file sharing, if the requirements are fulfilled.

P.S. I'm not going to recommend a particular product here as it goes against Serverfault's policy. You can search for it in internet and find one that best suits your need.

Comment: I am looking for a third party option, I will edit the question to make that clearer. Also, Microsoft has withdrawn their media pack that allows the upgrade to 8.1 pro. If you edit this answer to explain how to use one of the third party options, I'll accept it and reward the bounty :)

Comment: @Basil, as you can see, I have updated my answer and removed the third party software names, as product recommendation goes against serverfault's policy. The one softwared that I have found [Ex2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) seems robust and easy to me. But I haven't tried it yet. You can give it a try,

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want stability then you should opt for commercial solution. I tried several free client but they were all very unstable. Long time ago I had good experience with unix client software from Hummingbird. I guess the company was acquired by OpenText now but the software is still available and maintained. [Here is a link](http://connectivity.opentext.com/products/nfs-clients.aspx). Depending on your situation $245 may be too steep for a single piece of software though.